# How To check for environment vars during django startup

Tags: python, django, environment-variables

Id like to have my secret keys loaded via environment vars that shall be check on startup of my Django app. Im using an AppConfig for that purpose, because that code will be executed on startup.

For now i wrote a little helper to get the vars and a list of vars to check. Which is working fine. 
The problem:

I also wrote a Django management command to help entering and storing the needed vars and save em to the users .profile, BUT when i have my checks in place the AppConfig will raise errors before i even have the chance to run my configuration command :(

So how do i enable that configuration management command whilst still having that env check run on startup?

For now im going to do a plain python script to not load Django at all (which i dont need for now anyways), but in case i might need to alter the database (and thus need Django for some setup task) how would i be able to sneak past my own startup check in my AppConf?

Where else might i be placing the checks?
I tried the main urls.py, but this will only be loaded once the first url lookup is needs and thus one might start the server and not see any errors and still the app will not work once the first url is entered in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, it turned out that the AppConfig is not the right spot for a task like that .. i realized my loading of secrets with a modification of the projects manage.py and im planning to release an app with all of the code in the near furture :)